# Do all HTML elements go in a <div> tag in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble figuring out if all HTML element has to be the `<div>` tag while using bootstrap.

I know that's the case with creating a row but, what if I create a nav? Does the `<li>` have to be in the `<div>`?

Comment: div element will create a horizontal block which you can use as a container to hold your nav elements

Answer (score 1):

There are classes and style set by bootstrap you have to use.. you can customize it as per your need but yes you need  to create blocks for your LI to warp it around the specific area of your webpage.

here is the basic example of header and sidebar using nav (bootstrap)

```
    <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
      <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
      <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      </a>

      <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <!-- Messages: style can be found in dropdown.less-->
          <li class="dropdown messages-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
              <span class="label label-success">4</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="header">You have 4 messages</li>
              <li>
                <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
                <ul class="menu">
                  <li><!-- start message -->
                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                      </div>
                      <h4>
                        Support Team
                        <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 5 mins</small>
                      </h4>
                      <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <!-- end message -->
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="dist/img/user3-128x128.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                      </div>
                      <h4>
                        AdminLTE Design Team
                        <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 hours</small>
                      </h4>
                      <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="dist/img/user4-128x128.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                      </div>
                      <h4>
                        Developers
                        <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Today</small>
                      </h4>
                      <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="dist/img/user3-128x128.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                      </div>
                      <h4>
                        Sales Department
                        <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Yesterday</small>
                      </h4>
                      <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="pull-left">
                        <img src="dist/img/user4-128x128.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                      </div>
                      <h4>
                        Reviewers
                        <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2 days</small>
                      </h4>
                      <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="footer"><a href="#">See All Messages</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- Notifications: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
          <li class="dropdown notifications-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
              <span class="label label-warning">10</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="header">You have 10 notifications</li>
              <li>
                <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
                <ul class="menu">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i> 5 new members joined today
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-warning text-yellow"></i> Very long description here that may not fit into the
                      page and may cause design problems
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-users text-red"></i> 5 new members joined
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart text-green"></i> 25 sales made
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-user text-red"></i> You changed your username
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="footer"><a href="#">View all</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- Tasks: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
          <li class="dropdown tasks-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <i class="fa fa-flag-o"></i>
              <span class="label label-danger">9</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="header">You have 9 tasks</li>
              <li>
                <!-- inner menu: contains the actual data -->
                <ul class="menu">
                  <li><!-- Task item -->
                    <a href="#">
                      <h3>
                        Design some buttons
                        <small class="pull-right">20%</small>
                      </h3>
                      <div class="progress xs">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-aqua" style="width: 20%" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                          <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <!-- end task item -->
                  <li><!-- Task item -->
                    <a href="#">
                      <h3>
                        Create a nice theme
                        <small class="pull-right">40%</small>
                      </h3>
                      <div class="progress xs">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-green" style="width: 40%" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                          <span class="sr-only">40% Complete</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <!-- end task item -->
                  <li><!-- Task item -->
                    <a href="#">
                      <h3>
                        Some task I need to do
                        <small class="pull-right">60%</small>
                      </h3>
                      <div class="progress xs">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-red" style="width: 60%" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                          <span class="sr-only">60% Complete</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <!-- end task item -->
                  <li><!-- Task item -->
                    <a href="#">
                      <h3>
                        Make beautiful transitions
                        <small class="pull-right">80%</small>
                      </h3>
                      <div class="progress xs">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-yellow" style="width: 80%" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                          <span class="sr-only">80% Complete</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <!-- end task item -->
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="footer">
                <a href="#">View all tasks</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- User Account: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
          <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
              <span class="hidden-xs">Alexander Pierce</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <!-- User image -->
              <li class="user-header">
                <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">

                <p>
                  Alexander Pierce - Web Developer
                  <small>Member since Nov. 2012</small>
                </p>
              </li>
              <!-- Menu Body -->
              <li class="user-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#">Followers</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#">Sales</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#">Friends</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
              </li>
              <!-- Menu Footer-->
              <li class="user-footer">
                <div class="pull-left">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Profile</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- Control Sidebar Toggle Button -->
          <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="control-sidebar"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
  <aside class="main-sidebar">
    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <section class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel -->
      <div class="user-panel">
        <div class="pull-left image">
          <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left info">
          <p>Alexander Pierce</p>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- search form -->
      <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </span>
        </div>
      </form>
      <!-- /.search form -->
      <!-- sidebar menu: : style can be found in sidebar.less -->
      <ul class="sidebar-menu">
        <li class="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
        <li class="active treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Dashboard v1</a></li>
            <li><a href="index2.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Dashboard v2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>
            <span>Layout Options</span>
            <span class="label label-primary pull-right">4</span>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="pages/layout/top-nav.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Top Navigation</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/layout/boxed.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Boxed</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/layout/fixed.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Fixed</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/layout/collapsed-sidebar.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Collapsed Sidebar</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="pages/widgets.html">
            <i class="fa fa-th"></i> <span>Widgets</span>
            <small class="label pull-right bg-green">new</small>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-pie-chart"></i>
            <span>Charts</span>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="pages/charts/chartjs.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> ChartJS</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/charts/morris.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Morris</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/charts/flot.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Flot</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/charts/inline.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Inline charts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>
            <span>UI Elements</span>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="pages/UI/general.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> General</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/UI/icons.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Icons</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/UI/buttons.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Buttons</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/UI/sliders.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Sliders</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/UI/timeline.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Timeline</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/UI/modals.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Modals</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <span>Forms</span>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="pages/forms/general.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> General Elements</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/forms/advanced.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Advanced Elements</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/forms/editors.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Editors</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-table"></i> <span>Tables</span>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="pages/tables/simple.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Simple tables</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/tables/data.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Data tables</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="pages/calendar.html">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <span>Calendar</span>
            <small class="label pull-right bg-red">3</small>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="pages/mailbox/mailbox.html">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> <span>Mailbox</span>
            <small class="label pull-right bg-yellow">12</small>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> <span>Examples</span>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="pages/examples/invoice.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Invoice</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/examples/profile.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/examples/login.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/examples/register.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/examples/lockscreen.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Lockscreen</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/examples/404.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> 404 Error</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/examples/500.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> 500 Error</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/examples/blank.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Blank Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/examples/pace.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Pace Page</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-share"></i> <span>Multilevel</span>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level One</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level One <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
              <ul class="treeview-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Two</a></li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Two <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>
                  <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Three</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level Three</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Level One</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="documentation/index.html"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>Documentation</span></a></li>
        <li class="header">LABELS</li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o text-red"></i> <span>Important</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o text-yellow"></i> <span>Warning</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o text-aqua"></i> <span>Information</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use li as li, basically you can use all elements as usual and if necessary, you can add bootstrap classes to the element. 
check the doc here http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5, you can use `<nav>` tag to group a block of elements and indicate they are part of the navigation.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#1">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

`<li>` tag defines a list item and usually sits inside `<ul>` or `<ol>` tag. You can wrap your navigation section in a `<div>` and apply appropriate bootstrap class to it, e.g. `container`, `row`, etc.

Comment: `li` doesn't _usually_ sits inside an `ul`/`ol`, it _always_ does (if you want to have valid syntax)

Answer (score 0):

`div` elements are more commonly used as containers for additional code.

Bootstrap uses classes to define what styling would be applied to an element. There are several other elements which has the same job of the `div` element, but are called something different. These are mostly [new HTML5 elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp). You can use these as well as `div` elements to produce websites.

For example, in HTML5 you can use the `nav` element to define the navigation of the website. You can also define Bootstrap classes in it too.

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Portfolio</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

It is recommended you use elements such as `header`, `main`, and `footer` to increase accessibility on your websites.